# Finding the number of combinations of two dates from n dates where one precedes the other?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that I am given n consecutive dates for buying and selling shares . So what are the number of ways of choosing a **pair of buy date and sell date** such that buy date always precede sale date ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick any two distinct dates. There are $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ways to do this. Label the earlier one buy, the later one sell.

I have interpreted "earlier" as meaning different. It is always possible to buy one day and sell later the same day. With that interpretation, there are $n$ additional possibilities.

Comment: Can you explain how is it n(n−1)/2? What is the term inside the brackets called ?

Comment: This is a **binomial coefficient**. One high school notation for the same thing is ${}_n\text{C}_2$, often pronounced in english "$n$ choose $2$." There are other notations, like $C(n,2)$, or $C_2^n$. To see that there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ways to do this, write down one date. There are $n$ ways to do this. For each choice, there are $n-1$ ways to write a different date, for a total of $n(n-1)$. For half these choices, the first date chosen will be later than the second date chosen.So the number of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a$ is earlier than $b$ is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.